# Hibernate table inheritance and subclass properties with same name only mapping for one table

Tags: sql, hibernate, inheritance

I am using Hibernate joined inheritance (1 root table, and 2 sub-tables). For instance:

- Root class: Entity (mapped to table `enti`)
- Subclasses: Person (`pers`) and Company (`comp`)

Person and Company both have the field `email`, but for legacy reasons I cannot unify the `email` field in the root class Entity. The mapping looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enti")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
class Entity {
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "pers")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
@XmlRootElement
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "discriminator_pers")
@Indexed
class Person {
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email; // getter + setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comp")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
@XmlRootElement
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "discriminator_comp")
@Indexed
class Company {
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email; // getter + setter
}
```

When using the hibernate criteria API in the `email` field, hibernate is only able to map to the first field it can find, which is the `comp` email field.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Entity.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("email", "email@email.com"));
```

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
select ...
from enti this_
left outer join comp this_1_ on this_.id = this_1_.id
left outer join pers this_2_ on this_.id = this_2_.id
where this_1_.email = ?
```

One solution would be: map `comp.email` to `companyEmail` and `pers.email` to `personEmail` in each entity, but it would mean a lot of refactoring.

Is it possible to use the same field name in both subclasses and have hibernate search on both tables?

Comment: Same problem, still looking for a solution